# How to set "twitter:player" URL in Twitter player card?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-integration, iframe

I am trying to design Twitter player cards for my podcast episodes, which are hosted on a Wordpress site. I am confused about what is supposed to go in this section:

```
<meta name="twitter:player" content="">
```

The only information I can find from Twitter about this field is that it is an: "HTTPS URL to iframe player. This must be a HTTPS URL which does not generate mixed content warnings in a web browser. Required."

So how does one know what URL to use? Are there free players available that anyone can link to in their Twitter card? Should the player be self-hosted?

My site uses the [Podlove Web Player](http://podlove.org/podlove-web-player/) to play episodes of my podcast ([example post here](http://podcast.rujic.net/?p=201)). I'd prefer to use that player since I've already got it set up for each of my episodes, but I don't know enough about this whole Twitter card thing to know if that is possible.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather you have to give twitter a URL to a separate page on your site with only the video. This is used as the URL for an iframe on Twitter.

So if you set up a page on your site with the video on it's own (no header/footer/logo or anything else) called `www.example.com/video.html` your twitter card html would be: `<meta name="twitter:player" content="https://www.example.com/video.html">`.

Twitter's docs go into detail on the format required, how apps and their mobile site must be set up. They also mention that they review player cards. So it's worth combing through these and making sure all work.

To avoid mixed content warnings you'll have to make sure your https page only includes https resources, i.e. all links to javascript or video files must be served over https.